# Django `ImageFile.read()` raises `bytes` object has no attribute `read`

Tags: python, django, file

This is the model I'm using:

```py
from django import models


class Image(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/images/')
```

Now, if I do `image.file.read()` I get `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'`

```py
>>> from images.models import Image
>>> img = Image.objects.first()
>>> img.file.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\utils.py", line 42, in <lambda>
    read = property(lambda self: self.file.read)
  File "...\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\utils.py", line 42, in <lambda>
    read = property(lambda self: self.file.read)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
```

`image.file.file.file` returns a `bytes` object and not a `File` object. I'm using Django 4.2.1 with python 3.10.7.

The following piece of code solves it, but is not a viable workaround.

```py
import io

from images.models import Image


img = Image.objects.first()
img.file.file.file = io.BytesIO(img.file.file.file)

img.file.read() # Runs without errors
```

I believe that `image.file.file.file` should be a `File` object but it is returning a `bytes` object instead. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: My reading of the documentation is that you should be using just `img.read()`.  I can find no reference to a `file` attribute.

Comment: @jasonharper `img` is the model instance. Models don't have a `read()` method. `img.file` is the file which has the method, but since the `img.file.file.file` should be a file but is a bytes object an error is raised.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue with the same version of Django & python - I couldn't find any problems.

Comment: Moreover, if the `img.file` is returning `bytes`, then definitely you can not access `img.file.file` since it will raise an `AttributeError` for sure

Comment: `img.file` is not returning bytes. What is returning bytes is `img.file.file.file`. `img.file` returns an `ImageFile` object, `img.file.file` returns a `File` object, and `img.file.file.file` returns bytes.

Answer (score 0):

After checking my storage library's code, I found that the error was in the library itself.

```py
from django.core.file import File

import requests


class BunnyStorage(Storage):
    def _open(self, name, mode='rb'): 
        resp = requests.get(self.base_url + name, headers=self.headers)

        if resp.status_code == 404: 
            raise ValueError('File not found.')

        return File(resp.content)
```

After replacing `File` with `io.BytesIO` (which is a file-like object) the error stopped being raised.